# The "background-color" and "border-color" properties of a link are not modified with CSS

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

I have been able to modify the color of the text of a visited link but I haven't could modify the "background-color" and "border-color" properties of it. The first part of the internal style sheet is a CSS reset.

```css
a:visited {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Ve a Google</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you even try to look this up ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Answer (score 3):

for modify background-color you should first set background-color for a:link and then for a:vizited.
also border-color is invalid property value for link.

```
<html>
   <style> 
a:link{
background-color:white;
}
a:visited{
color:red;
background-color:blue;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Ve 
  a Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of security issues, the `:visited` pseudo-class has a lot of limitations placed on it on what you can style. To quote from [the Mozilla developer wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector):

> You can style visited links, but there are limits to which styles you can use. Only the following styles can be applied to visited links:
>
> - `color`
> - `background-color`
> - `border-color` (and its sub-properties)
> - `column-rule-color`
> - `outline-color`
> - The color parts of the `fill` and `stroke` attributes

If you are having issues styling the `background-color` property, it could be an issue with your CSS reset stylesheet specifying a transparent background colour for `<a>` tags.